# How to make a floating bottom button like this? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, widget

I want to make a page bottom bar like the bottom bar with floating widgets in this image:

[image]

How can the button be floating? please give me the code without any package.

My Code

```dart
return Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: Stack(
      children: [

      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Does using a NavigationBar() or BottomNavigationBar(), with a FloatingActionButton() or FloatingActionButton.extend() not work? Also, scaffold has a floatingActionBarLocation property where you can set it has docked or floating.